# Deselect row in QTableWidget when clicked for a second time

Tags: qt, selection, qtablewidget, deselect

I have `QTableWidget::selectionMode` - `SingleSelection`, `QTableWidget::selectionBehavior` - `SelectRows`. So user selects rows via single click. However, when clicking the same row again, it isn't deselected. How to implement such deselection?

Comment: Does multiple selection is allowed by your application logic?

Comment: @Gluttton: currently not, it's in TODO for future release

Comment: Does deselect using `click + Ctrl` is acceptable for you?

Comment: @Gluttton: thanks for the information, it's nice that this can be already performed somehow, but simple deselection on second click would be better

Comment: `but simple deselection on second click would be better`, you need write some code to achieve it. You need handle mouse click on view and manually change selection.

Comment: You can try search `qtableview set maximum selected rows` - this is different issue, but similar approach.